# How to colour vertices and highlight links in igraph plot

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I'm new to `igraph` and I'm trying to plot small world networks where I color the vertices based on an attribute and highlight specific links.

Say I have an adjacency matrix (`adj_matrix`) for a network (`myNet`) with 8 vertices:

```
> adj_matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0
[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1
[8,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
```

And in a separate dataframe (`df`), I have 8 corresponding values:

```
> df
  name    values
1    1 0.3568838
2    2 0.5260344
3    3 0.3568838
4    4 0.7374865
5    5 0.7140553
6    6 0.5260344
7    7 0.4125705
8    8 0.7374865
```

As a makeshift solution, I can plot this as an undirected network with the vertices coloured by `nodes$values` manually like so:

```
as_edgelist(myNet, names = TRUE)

links <- data.frame(
  source=as_edgelist(myNet, names = TRUE)[,1],
  target=as_edgelist(myNet, names = TRUE)[,2])

palf <- colorRampPalette(c("gray80", "red"))
network <- graph_from_data_frame(d = links, vertices = df, directed = F)
plot(network, vertex.color = palf(8), layout=layout_in_circle)
```

[image]
But this is obviously tedious, and there must be a better way. Ideally there would be a way to use only an adjacency matrix to plot the edges and a vector of values to colour the vertices. How might I do this?

In addition, I'd like to know how to highlight (i.e., bold, change the colour, and/or change the line type) of a given edge.

Comment: Bolder edges are set with the edge-attribute `width`. Both vertices and edges take `color` (American spelling only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can colour vertices and edges in igraph by specifying values of `vertex.color` and `edge.color` when you `plot()`.

So far so good in your example, but **you should really try to work with igraph-objects** instead of your makeshift solutions. Consider making your graph with `graph_from_edgelist()` or `graph_from_adjacency_matrix()`.

The igraph-object naturally plots verticy-attributes like `color` and edge-attributes like `color` and `width`. You could set them setting them like so:

```
V(network)$color <- "white"
V(network)$color <- "black"
```

Note also, that your code above doesn't colour edges according to your values in the `df`, but rather as a linear gradient from gray to red generated by your `palf()` :)

**This code replicates your example data**

```
df <- data.frame(name=1:8, values=c(0.3568838,0.5260344, 0.3568838,0.7374865,0.7140553,0.5260344,0.4125705,0.7374865))
g <- make_empty_graph(n=8, directed=F) %>% add_edges(c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,8,1,8,8,7,7,6,6,5))
adj_matrix <- as.matrix(as_adjacency_matrix(g))
```

**This is how you could start colouring and highlighting**

```
# Make network and assign values from dataframe
network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj_matrix, mode="undirected")
V(network)$value <- df$values
V(network)$col_values <- round( V(network)$value, 2) * 100

# Colour vertecies
colours <- colorRampPalette(c("gray80", "red"))(100)
V(network)$color <- colours[ V(network)$col_values ]

# Color edges
E(network)$color <- "black"

#Highlight edge
E(network)$width <- 1
E(network)$width[5] <- 5

# Plot
plot(network, layout=layout_in_circle)
```

A very straightforward way, if your data-frames are in order, is to directly assign attributes to edges and vertices when creating the network using `graph_from_data_frame()`. Just make sure that the data-frames for vertices and edges actuarially **have columns named** `color` or `width` or whatever other values you would like to set and appropriate values for those attributes.

See the manual `?graph_from_data_frame()` for a good example.